# Search in files with wildcards in sublime

Tags: sublimetext2

In the sublime text editor, how do you search recursively in a directory for only certain file types? E.g. in a directory for all *.cc and *.h files?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Specify the path in the Find 'Where' field and wildcards after the path seperated by commas.

e.g. `/path/to/search,*.cc,*.h`

Comment: Putting the file types before the path also works (e.g. `*.cc, *.h, /path/to/search`)

Answer (score 13):

You can also exclude file-types with the minus '-' character: `/path/,-*.xml`