# How to use wildcards in search paths?

Tags: sublimetext2

Is it possible to use a wildcard in a path ("Where" input) ?  I know [it's possible for the files names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185384/search-in-files-with-wildcards-in-sublime), but I can't find how to use wildcards in the path itself.
For instance, **I'd like to perform this search**:

```
/home/john/dev/*/branch_name,*.py
```

The reason is that I have 3 dev branches with the same name (`branch_name`) but belonging to different projects.  But the wildcard `*` doesn't work.  So far, my only alternative solution is to perform 3 searches:

```
/home/john/dev/project1/branch_name,*.py
/home/john/dev/project2/branch_name,*.py
/home/john/dev/project3/branch_name,*.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the `...` button next to the where field.  You can include multiple directories if they're comma-separated or use the `Add Folder` option. There are a couple other options there too that might help.

Comment: Rats, i was hoping for a regex, i have many, many directories and I only want to search within particular ones (of which there are still many!)

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, the trick is to use a regex within the filter, not the folder spec, e.g.:
with a root folder `"/home/john/dev/"`, use a filter `".*/branch_name/.*\.py"`, e.g., the 'where' string would be:

```
/home/john/dev,.*/branch_name/.*\.py
```