# Using wildcards in C# for path names

Tags: c#, wildcard

I'm trying to create a C# program that searches a directory based and finds certain files based on user input (multiple .xml files named by date.) Right now I am starting small and just trying to filter out all the possible xml files regardless of name:

```
arrAllFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"/directory1/directory2,*.xml");
```

I'm getting an error that I'm almost positive is because I am not using the wildcard correctly. I'm not very familiar with C# but based on what I found online ([Search in files with wildcards in sublime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185384/search-in-files-with-wildcards-in-sublime)) but this seems like it should work? When I run it without the wildcard and xml part it works fine and returns the name of every file within the directory. Any help would be much appreciated!

(Not sure if I should have specified but I am using Visual Studio for this)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Whenever you ask a question which involves saying you get an error, please indicate exactly what the error is, otherwise it's much harder to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you're providing a single argument to `GetFiles`. You need to provide two *separate* arguments:

```
arrAllFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"/directory1/directory2", "*.xml");
```

Note that `@"/directory1/directory2"` and `"*.xml"` are two separate strings here - whereas the code you'd provided has a *single* string including a comma.

Also note that the question you refer to is about how to find files in Sublime Text, a text editor - that's very different from making a call to a method.